# CodeIgniter - Uploading CSV to database issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, csv

I have an application where I want a user to be able to upload a list of contacts via CSV and save them to the database. I've tried to setup [brad stinsons CSV codeigniter library](https://github.com/bradstinson/csv-import) but been having trouble so far... When I click on upload, the CSV just disappears and goes nowhere, without any errors..

If anyone could inform me on whether I'm on the right track or just completely off I'd really appreciate it.

Here is my `Csv_import.php` Controller

```
public function load_data() {

    $result = $this->csv_import_model->select();
    $output = 'contacttable';
    $count = 0;
    if($result->num_rows() > 0)

    {
        foreach ($result->result() as $row)
        {
            $count = $count + 1;
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$count.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->fullname.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->email'.</td>
            <td>'.$row->country'.</td>
            <td>'.$row->gender'.</td>
            </tr>';

        }

    }
    else {
        $output .='<p>Data not available</p>';

    }
    $output .= '</table></div>';
    echo $output;


}

public function import()
{
    $file_data = $this->csvimport->get_array($_FILES["csv_file"] 
    ["tmp_name"]);

    foreach($file_data as $row)
    {
        $data[] = array (

        'fullname' => $row["fullname"],
        'email' => $row["email"],
        'country' =>$row["country"],
        'gender' =>$row["gender"]
        );

    }
    $this->csv_import_model->insert($data);
}
```

my `Csv_Import_model.php` model

```
class Csv_import_model extends CI_model
{
    function select()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('idcontacts', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('contacts');
        return $query; 
    }


    function insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert_batch('contacts', $data);
    }
}
```

My View on dashboard

```
<form method="post" id="import_csv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select CSV File</label>
        <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" required accept=".csv" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="import_csv" class="btn btn-info" 
    id="import_csv_btn">Import CSV</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="imported_csv_data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by following the git repository in this [link](https://github.com/jadirullah/Codeigniter-Impor-Csv-to-Mysql)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Github page of bradstinson/csv-import](https://github.com/bradstinson/csv-import):

> **CSV Import [DEPRECATED]**
>
> CSV Import is a Codeigniter spark which makes it easy to import a CSV file into an associative array.
>
> NOTE: I've not used this code in about 3 years, and will no longer offer any type of support. However, feel free to use this code at your own risk.

As such, I strongly advised you against using a deprecated library for your application.

Note that you don't have to look for a CSV library dedicated to CodeIgniter. Any PHP library can be loaded inside CI. This is preferably done through [Composer autoloading](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html).

With a quick search, I could recommend:

1. Did you know that PHP has [its very own function (fgetcsv)](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse CSV file? It has its shortcomings (not respecting quoted string, or multilined CSV), but it may work in your case.
2. [parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php) which implements the [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) (CSV standard) and looks actively maintained. It can be loaded with Composer.

Here is an example using `fgetcsv`:

```
if (($handle = fopen("myfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // Process with $data
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Here is an example using `parsecsv`:

```
$csv = new ParseCsv\Csv();
$csv->delimiter = ",";
$csv->parse('my-file.csv');
foreach($csv->data as $row) {
    // Process using $row
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will look into these

Comment: How does it look? :)

Comment: i was able to get it working using this https://github.com/jadirullah/Codeigniter-Impor-Csv-to-Mysql

Comment: ...Which uses `fgetcsv` internally. Maybe add this link as an answer so it may help other people :)